# Why is the last command not executing?

Tags: php, laravel, bash, docker-compose

I made a github gist to scaffold a Laravel Jetstream with Storybook from the oficial Laravel installer but the last command is not running.

Here is the code:

```sh
curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash

cd example-app

./vendor/bin/sail up -d;
docker-compose exec -T -u sail laravel.test bash -c "
composer require laravel/jetstream \
&& php artisan jetstream:install inertia --teams \
&& npm install \
&& npx sb@next init --builder webpack5";
./vendor/bin/sail down
```

So this gist is hosted in some `url` and I run it by

`curl -s <url> | bash`

It runs fine but the last command
`./vendor/bin/sail down`
is never running.

The last output I can see is the successful npm output

Comment: Could it be due to a missing final newline?

Comment: I don't think so as the first command is a nested bash like this one and it runs fine with no final newline.  
 You can check it in [https://laravel.build/example-app](https://laravel.build/example-app)  
I modified the gist to add the final endline but there is no change on behaviour.

Comment: Try putting something trivial such as `echo "End of file"` as the last statement, just to check whether the command is executed without effect / with errors or is not executed at all

Comment: I checked to print `echo &?` to check the second to last command and the exit is zero

Comment: I also tried 

```... ...
&& npx sb@next init --builder webpack5"; ./vendor/bin/sail down
```
and it runs fine

Comment: ```... ...
&& npx sb@next init --builder webpack5" && ./vendor/bin/sail down```
Also works
I am pretty lost by this results